# How to send custom form submissions to WordPress Database?

Tags: php, database, forms

I have created a form and the table in the database I want submissions to be sent to. From my research I've found that this code should send it to the database:

```
<?php /* PHP code that processes form */
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        global $wpdb;
        $tablename = Form_Submissions;
      
        $data=array(
            'FirstName' => $_POST['fname'],
            'LastName' => $POST['lname'],
            'Consent' => $POST['consent']
        );
        
        $format = array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        );
      
        $wpdb -> insert($tablename, $data, $format);

        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("frm").style.display="none"; </script>';
    }
?>
```

However, nothing is happening. I'm at complete loss on where to go from here. Am I missing something simple, or am I completely off target? Thank you for your help!

Here is the code for the form and the code that activates the form just in case.

```
<html>
<style>

/* Stylings for Heading Statement */
    .h3{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Stylings for checkbox */
    .box{
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 20px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Stylings for input labels (names and checkbox labels) */
    .input-label{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
    .open-button {
        width: 170px; 
        height: 60px; 
        background-color: transparent; 
        outline: none; 
        position: relative; 
        left: -168px; 
        top: 20px;
    }
/* The popup form - hidden by default */
    .form-popup {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: -530px;
        border: none;
        z-index: 9;
        background-color: #1e1e1e;
        width: 1000px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
/* Sets style and size of input fields  */
    .form-popup input[type=text] {
        width: 30%;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
        border: none;
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
/* Sets color and style of the input boxes when selected */
    .form-popup input:focus {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        outline: none;
    }
/* Stylings of the submit button */
    .btn {
        background-color: #DB2600;
        border-radius: 9999px;
        font-size: 24px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 45px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        color: white;
    }
/* Changes the color of the sugmit button when curser hovers over it */
    .btn:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
/* Hides the default checkbox */
    .box input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
/* creates custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
/* Sets the color of checkbox when checked */
    .box input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #DB2600;
    }
/* creates checkmark inside checkbox */
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
/* Displays checkmark when checkbox is clicked */
    .box input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }
/* Positions and styles checkmark */
    .box .checkmark:after {
        left: 7px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 6px;
        height: 12px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
/* Column formatting for checkbos and statement. This is what is aligning the two items. */
    .column1 {
        float: left;
        width: 26%;
    }
    .column2 {
        float: left;
        width: 74%;
        margin-top:-5px;
    }
/* Clears floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

</style>
<body>

<!-- Code for the form -->

    <div class="form-popup" id="Form"> 
        <form method="post">
        
        <!-- acknolwdgement statment -->
              <h3 class="h3">form statement</h3> 

        <!-- label and input for First Name -->
              <label for="fname" class="input-label">First name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="fname" required/>

        <!-- label and input for Last Name -->
              <label for="lname" class="input-label">&nbsp &nbsp Last name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="lname" required/> <br> <br>

        <!-- checkbox and label, placed to columns to achieve desired formating -->
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="column1" style="text-align: right;">
                      <label  class="box" style="border-color: red;">  
                      <input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="agree" class="box" required/>
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                      </label></div>
                  <div class="column2" style="text-align: left;">
                      <label class="input-label"> I have read and understand the above statement.
                      </label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <br><br>  

        <!-- Submit Button -->
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">

        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    function openForm() { /* Opens Consent Form */
        document.getElementById("Form").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

</body>


<?php /* PHP code that processes form */
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        global $wpdb;
        $tablename = Form_Submissions;
      
        $data=array(
            'FirstName' => $_POST['fname'],
            'LastName' => $POST['lname'],
            'Consent' => $POST['consent']
        );
        
        $format = array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        );
      
        $wpdb -> insert($tablename, $data, $format);

        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("frm").style.display="none"; </script>';
    }
?>
</html>
```

The Switch Case that activates it:

```
<?php /* code for pop-up button conditions */
$host = 'https://' .$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; /* gets the current page's URL */
switch ( $host ){
  case 'https://example1.com': 
  case 'https://example2.com': 
  case 'https://example3.com':
    require 'pop-up-button.php'; /*calls the PHP file containing the code for the form*/
    echo '<button id="close" class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"></button>'; 
    break; 
  default : /* the default case leaves the function and allows all pages with URL's not match the cases to run as normal pages */
    break; 
}; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have seen it now, lastname and consent have $POST instead of $_POST, $POST it will be a php variable, the correct is $_POST. Maybe the error is that all along.

Anyhow, with query must work, if it doesnt or is the sql statement not correct or there is no connection with the database

```php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("update pro_slider set pos = {$d} where id = {$f->id};"));
```

this is something I use, to update a banner in my case.
for your case you should use the insert statement.

```php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("insert into {$table_name} values ( 0 , 0, 0, 0  ) "));
```

just replace the zeros with the desired, I would try before use hard code values, if it works, it's all working just fine, just replace the hard code (writted values) with the variables, just bear in mind that varchar could need comas, and sometimes sql statment is a little weird with $_POST directly on the sql statement, sometimes need to have it on a php variable.

alright,this is what I would do step by step to check the issue.

```php
global $wpdb;
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$Consent = $_POST['consent'];
$sql = "insert into {$table_name} values ( {$first_name} , {$LastName}, {$Consent} )";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sql);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

this should print something like

insert into custom_table values ( 'Brad', 'Pitt', 1)

in this case the statment is correct, however if it prints like this

insert into custom_table values ( Brad, Pitt, 1)

this isnt correct, Brad is not a varchar and needs to be between comas, so lets insert comas in the code:

```php
global $wpdb;
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$Consent = $_POST['consent'];
$sql = "insert into {$table_name} values ( '{$first_name}' , '{$LastName}', '{$Consent}' )";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sql);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

one of this will work just fine, I believe is the first, now just copy the $sql  and use it inside the wpdb->query

```php
global $wpdb;
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$Consent = $_POST['consent'];
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("insert into {$table_name} values ( {$first_name} , {$LastName}, {$Consent} ) "));
```

Answer (score 0):

the insert mode

```php
global $wpdb;
$FirstName = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$Consent = $_POST['consent'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'Form_Submissions';
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array('FirstName' => $FirstName, 'LastName' => $LastName, 'Consent' => $Consent));
```

depending on your table, if they are varchar or not, the variables sometimes need to be between comas like so. I making this without testing, with array possible dont need this, nevertheless...

```php
global $wpdb;
$FirstName = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$Consent = $_POST['consent'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'Form_Submissions';
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array('FirstName' => "$FirstName", 'LastName' => "$LastName", 'Consent' => "$Consent"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but neither of these worked.

Comment: Have seen it now, lastname and consent have $POST instead of $_POST, $POST it will be a php variable, the correct is $_POST. Maybe the error is that all along.  correct your code. the example above I have corrected now. if your code still doesnt work try again this one, if somehow still doesnt work use the $wpdb->query.  it must work.